# Classification using two text columns and categorical column

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-models, natural-language, multi-class

I have an audit data which contains 4 columns that I want to apply the classification on. The columns are type of observation(Categorical), Observation(Text), Type of Recommendation(Categorical) and Recommendation(Text). I want to create a model which would take the two text columns and and type of observation column and output type of recommendation. Is it possible to do so? If yes, how would you suggest I go about it.